# How to interpret the supervised contrastive loss

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I am currently trying to wrap my head around the supervised contrastive loss introduced in the following article : https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.11362.pdf

The loss formula in question is :

$$Loss = \sum_{i \in I} \frac{-1}{|P(i)|} \sum_{p \in P(i)} log \frac{exp(z_i . z_p / \tau)}{\sum_{a \in A(i)} exp(z_i . z_a / \tau)} $$

With $ P(i) = \{p \in A(i) : y_p = y_i \}$, the indices of all the positives of i, distinct from i.

$ A(i) = I \setminus \{i\}$ all indices of the data, distinct from i.

And $\tau$ a temperature parameter (around $0.05$).

The intuition behind the contrastive loss is that we wish to push the negatives (i.e. instances with a different class) away from the anchor, and pull the positives closer to the anchor.

So, my confusion comes from the denominator, which includes both negatives and **positives**. Because the dot product $z_i . z_p \approx 1$ when $x_i$ and $x_p$ are of the same class, $exp(z_i . z_p / \tau)$ is large. And in the same way, $exp(z_i . z_p / \tau) \approx 0$ when $x_i$ and $x_p$ are of a different class (because $z_i . z_n \approx -1$)

We want the ratio of the exponential must be close to 1 to get $log(1)=0$, but the denominator includes many positives, and thus becomes very large, and much larger than the numerator. The model will thus never converge, which is something that I have confirmed experimentally.

So have I misunderstood this loss function, and how does it work ?